# change value of an array of nested objects to a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

this is the array that i currently have

```js
const myArr = [
    {
      "code": {
        "value": "AC16",
        "description": "text"
      },
      "convictionDate": {
        "value": "2019-03-07"
      }
    },
    {
      "code": {
        "value": "AC20",
        "description": "text"
      },
      "convictionDate": {
        "value": "2019-03-06"
      }
    }
  ];
```

I want to map over each nested object inside the array so that the value of each nested object is the value property of that object as a string. so the object would become:

```js
const myArr = [
    {
      "code": "AC16",
      "convictionDate":"2019-03-07"
    },
    {
      "code":"AC20",
      "convictionDate": "2019-03-06"
    }
  ]
```

Ive tried this with no success:

```js
const x = myArr.map((item)=>{
        console.log(item)
        Object.keys(item).map(function(key,i) {
            item[key] = item[key][value];
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just use array map

```js
const myArr = [{
    "code": {
      "value": "AC16",
      "description": "text"
    },
    "convictionDate": {
      "value": "2019-03-07"
    }
  },
  {
    "code": {
      "value": "AC20",
      "description": "text"
    },
    "convictionDate": {
      "value": "2019-03-06"
    }
  }
];

let newArray = myArr.map(function(item) {
  return {
    code: item.code.value,
    convictionDate: item.convictionDate.value

  }

});
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Map the array, and reduce the entries to the required object form:

```js
const myArr = [{"code":{"value":"AC16","description":"text"},"convictionDate":{"value":"2019-03-07"}},{"code":{"value":"AC20","description":"text"},"convictionDate":{"value":"2019-03-06"}}];
  
const result = myArr.map(o =>
  Object.entries(o).reduce((r, [k, { value }]) => ({ ...r, [k]: value }), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myArr = [
    {
      "code": {
        "value": "AC16",
        "description": "text"
      },
      "convictionDate": {
        "value": "2019-03-07"
      }
    },
    {
      "code": {
        "value": "AC20",
        "description": "text"
      },
      "convictionDate": {
        "value": "2019-03-06"
      }
    }
  ];
  
let newArray = myArr.map(e => {
  return { "code":e.code.value, "convictionDate": e.convictionDate.value}
})

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes without saying there is some awesome reference material over at W3 Schools, the provide good detail on this in their [article here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

That said...

Why not simplify the code a little and try this against your array:-

```js
const myArr = [
    {
      "code": {
        "value": "AC16",
        "description": "text"
      },
      "convictionDate": {
        "value": "2019-03-07"
      }
    },
    {
      "code": {
        "value": "AC20",
        "description": "text"
      },
      "convictionDate": {
        "value": "2019-03-06"
      }
    }
  ];

// PROPOSED SOLUTION CODE
const x = myArr.map((item)=>{
        return {code: item.code.value,convictionDate: item.convictionDate.value}
    });

// Your Desired Example Provided in Question
const xArr = [
    {
      "code": "AC16",
      "convictionDate":"2019-03-07"
    },
    {
      "code":"AC20",
      "convictionDate": "2019-03-06"
    }
  ];

// Output Validation
console.log('Response of Array \'x\'');
console.log(x);
console.log('Your Desired Example');
console.log(xArr);
```

When using 'map'; we must map the source array ('myArr') to our new target array ('x').

In the context of the example code you have provided, 'data.convictions' is undefined.

The magic is all here:-

```
const x = myArr.map((item)=>{
        return {code: item.code.value,convictionDate: item.convictionDate.value}
    });
```

Happy coding!